# Grid System Behavior When div width not specified

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a piece of markup below, for which I do not understand the behavior in regards to the grid system.

I have a `container`. The `container` has one child, a `row`, and the `row` has three children, `div`'s with the class `col-lg`.

I understand what is happening at the `lg` breakpoint and higher - we are creating **3** equal-width columns. The `lg` in `col-lg` specifies the breakpoint to target, and since we didn't specify a size for our divs (for example, `col-lg-2`), they are equal-width.

My question is, what is happening at breakpoints smaller than `lg`? I can see the behavior is that each `div` inside of the `row` takes up all 12 columns, but the logic behind that behavior eludes me.

```
<div class="container pt-4" id="about">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg order-lg-2">
      <h3 class="mb-4">About Full Stack Conf</h3>
      <img class="mb-4 img-fluid rounded d-none d-sm-block" src="img/portland.jpg" alt="Portland, Oregon"/>
      <p>The beautiful city of Portland, Oregon will be the host city for Full Stack Conf!</p>
      <p>Explore the future of JavaScript with a lineup of industry professionals. Discover new techniques to advance your career as a web developer.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg order-lg-1">
      <h3 class="mb-4">Expert Speakers!</h3>
      <p>Our expert speaker lineup was just announced, so don't wait too long before grabbing your tickets!<p>
      <p>Nullam at iaculis augue. Maecenas nec pulvinar est, rutrum sodales quam. Aenean quis ornare orci. Praesent diam est, accumsan ac magna in, mattis mattis orci. Etiam turpis eros, tristique accumsan.<p>
      <p>Nunc gravida ultricies turpis, et varius leo malesuada quis. Proin scelerisque vitae leo eu tincidunt. Donec vestibulum urna ut ante venenatis congue. Fusce vehicula condimentum pharetra. Nulla fringilla dolor mauris.<p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg order-lg-3">
      <h3 class="mb-4">What You'll Learn</h3>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><strong>MongoDB</strong>: NoSQL Database</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><strong>Express</strong>: Framework for Node</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><strong>React</strong>: JavaScript library</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><strong>Node.js</strong>: JavaScript environment</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><strong>ES2015</strong>: Latest version of JavaScript</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><strong>Babel</strong>: JavaScript compiler</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your question related to *why* Bootstrap developers structured their Grid system in this fashion, or *how* the CSS is structured to achieve these results?

Answer (score 0):

so let me explain how it is when you define for example `.col-lg` its means you define `.col` within **breakpoint** so `.col-lg` means

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-lg {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

also any class it doesn't matter which **breakpoints** like `.col-lg, .col-sm, .col-xl, .col-md` all have the same styling its about the mobile first approach so **if you don't define a certain breakpoints** it will go with full width after your last breakpoints. it will always shrink after the last breakpoint you defined

so it takes this style and once you don't define anything by **default** all the `.col` class for bootstrap takes this styles

```
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

that's why its span the whole width so the **breakpoints** it's always **stronger** than the classes